# Collection of all small categories is a class

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

> *Axiom.* A class is a **set** if and only if it belongs to some (other) class
>
> *Comprehension schema.* If $\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a formula where quantification just occurs on sets variables, there exists a
> class $A$ such that  $$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in A\text{ if and only if
>  }\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n).$$
>
> *Definition.* A category $\mathcal{C}$ is called a **small category** when its class $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ of objects is a set.

I am trying to use the above to show that $\text{Ob}($**Cat**$):=\{\mathcal{C}\ |\ (\exists X)(\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})\in X)\}$ is a class: in other words, that the collection of all small categories is a class. I can't apply the comprehension schema because in the formula
$$(\exists X)(\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})\in X)$$ $X$ is quantified over and is not a set.

Where is my error?

**Edit:**

Do I even need to use comprehension to assert that $\{\mathcal{C}\ |\ (\exists X)(\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})\in X)\}$ is a class?

Comment: You do need comprehension to show that *anything* is a class. As for the error: don't quantify over a class variable for $X$? If $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set, then there exists a set that it's a member of; there's no need to quantify over classes for this.

Comment: e.g. its power set, correct?

Comment: Or pairing; either one.

Comment: I assume you're asking whether $\mathcal{C}$ is a *proper* class. It is clearly a class (it is a collection of sets, defined by a formula after all).